# Web API hosted under IIS throws exception - The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Web API hosted under IIS environment throws exception when accessed.

> "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The underlying
>   provider failed on
>   Open.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException"

Please let me know how can I make it working.

Comment: Ensure that your database connectionstring is correct and using that connectionstring you can connect to database

Comment: I have found the solution eventually, I needed to pass credential in the connection string to make it work.

Comment: If you found the answer, post it below and accept it.

Comment: I just added credentials in the connection string for sql server authentication and it worked.